# SQL query to join 2 tables and then combine columns and apply GroupBy on combined column

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark

I have 2 tables called Table1(Id,Name,Surname) and Table2(Id,Pincode)

Table 1 -

```
   Id   Name   Surname
    1    Ram    Charan
    2    Shyam  Mane
    3    Priya  Dhawal
    4    Ram    Charan
```

Table 2 -

```
Id  Pincode
1    445502
2    885934
3    485502
4    445502
```

I wan to join `Table1` and `Table2` on field `'Id'` and create column `Name|Surname|Pincode` by concatenating columns `Name,Surname,Pincode` and finally apply `GroupBy()` on `Name|Surname|Pincode`.

Expected output :-

```
Name|Surname|Pincode    Count of Ids
Ram|Charan|445502             2
Shyam|Mane|885934             1
Priya|Dhawal|485502           1
```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS('|', Name, Surname, Pincode) `Name|Surname|Pincode`,
       COUNT(*) `Count of Ids`
FROM table1
JOIN table2 USING (Id)
GROUP BY `Name|Surname|Pincode`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below simple query -

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name, '|', Surname, '|', Pincode) Name|Surname|Pincode, COUNT(*)
  FROM TABLE_1 T1
  JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id
 GROUP BY CONCAT(Name, '|', Surname, '|', Pincode);
```

Comment: I guess CONCAT(T1.Name, '|', T1.Surname, '|', T2.Pincode) , this is the right one?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare No difference - these names are not ambiguous.